# Python: Convert Integer to UTF16-LE

Tags: python, encoding, utf-16

I got an integer value of 29.827 and I want to convert this into the Unicode Han Character 'glass' (U+7483) (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7483/index.htm) with UTF-16-LE encoding.

I managed to convert this number into a 3-byte UTF-8 encoding (integers over 2048 have 3byte in UTF-8..) with

```
s ='\u%s'%hex(int_to_encode)[2:]
file.write(s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8'))
file.close()
```

But I figured out the needed encoding is UTF-16-LE.
In the intended encoding, an integer representation also has 3 bytes(this is why I thought my first try was correct, also 3 bytes for one integer...)

Thanks a lot for your Help,

Kind regards

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Unicode handling in Python 3 is rather different (and better) than in Python 2.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Still using 2.7 due to legacy code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all to convert a number to a character use `chr()` (Python3), or `unichr()` (Python2). Then to encode using UTF-16-LE you simply specify that encoding rather than specifying UTF-8.

So Python 2:

```
int_to_encode = 0x7483
s = unichr(int_to_encode)
file.write(s.encode('utf-16-le'))
file.close()
```

In either Python 2 or Python 3 you can specify the file encoding when you open it:

```
import io
s = unichr(0x7483)
with io.open('foo', 'w', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Console session to show this:

```
>>> with io.open('foo', 'w', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
...     f.write(unichr(0x7483))
...
1L
>>> with io.open('foo', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
...     print(f.read())
...
璃
```

Comment: :Thanks for your fast answer. But when I write the character to the file and open it with my editor, it shows "Coding CP1252". It is opened as "ƒt"

Comment: But Before writing to file and printing with  "int_to_encode = 0x7483; s = unichr(int_to_encode); print s" the character is shown correctly

Comment: It seems that file.write(s.encode('utf-16-le')) does not encode the character correctly...

Comment: The strange thing is, when i read the char from the file as you suggested with "with io.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
 print(f.read())" it works correctly

Comment: When i apply this method to my set of integers there seem to be some integers which are not correctly en/-decoded, because i yield a Decode Error: **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 1356-1357: illegal UTF-16 surrogate**

Comment: The problem with your editor is probably just that it doesn't know you are using utf-16-le. You can either tell your editor that that is the encoding which is being used, or you could include a BOM at the start of the file (though generally you should avoid using a BOM unless you really need one).

Comment: If you get a UnicodeDecodeError when writing to a file it means you didn't start with a unicode string: when writing the only thing you should be doing is *encoding*.

Comment: I figured out a strange error: For most of the integers this method does function, but for instance for integer "27658" I yield a "non-valid utf16-le document". Apart from this, when I just encode this 27658 into utf16-le and print the read with **with io.open('foo', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f: print(f.read())**, I get the error **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x6c in position 2: truncated data**

Comment: This exact behaviour, that for some integers the en-/and decoding does not properly function, led me to add a ***try:..... except UnicodeDecodeError***-statement for a data-stream in some previous project. I dont know what the problem is for some ints....

Comment: I now figured out the list of integers with don't en/and decode correctly: not_working_ints_list:   [27658, 27914, 28170, 28426, 28682, 28938, 29194, 29450, 29706, 29962, 30218, 30474, 30730, 30986, 31242, 31498, 31754, 32010, 32266, 32522]. This means 20times for a range of **range(27500, 32769)**, **which means for 20/5269*100% = 0.38 percent  of integers the en-and-decoding does not work properly** . Did some other people here encounter this?

Comment: It seems that this is a regularity...every 256th integer cant be en-and-decoded properly

Comment: Those are the ones that contain a byte with value 0x0a. I would guess that something is converting them to carriage-return+line-feed. Check how you are opening the file: if you are on windows, you will need to open the file in binary mode. 'wb' mode

Comment: nice info, thank you Duncan! I will try to handle this 0x0a separately